# Quiero sumar filas por medio de una condición

Tags: sql, .net, reportviewer

mi duda se trata de como sumar ciertas filas por medio de una condición, por ejemplo tengo la siguiente estructura en la tabla

| Exportador | Registrado | Aplica |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | 275 | No |
| Juan | 275 | No |
| Juan | 275 | Si |
| Juan | 275 | Si |

Quiero sumar todas las filas que en la columna **Aplica** diga **Si**, entonces en este caso me tendria que dar de resultado **550**.

El resultado final seria lo siguiente

| Exportador | Registrado |
| --- | --- |
| Juan | 550 |
| Otro | X |

Actualmente en mi reporte tengo lo siguiente

[image: ReportViewer]

Cree un grupo por exportador y la fórmula que utilice en el campo **Registrado** fue:

`=Sum(iif(Fields!solemRegAnaCafe.Value <> "No", Sum(Fields!contAnaRegAnaCafe.Value)),0))`

También intente con:
`=Sum(iif(Fields!solemRegAnaCafe.Value <> "No", Fields!contAnaRegAnaCafe.Value, 0))`

En los dos casos el resultado de la formula fue `#Error`.

En el único caso donde si me suma es en el siguiente:

`=IIf(Fields!contAnaRegAnaCafe.Value <> "No", Sum(Fields!contAnaSaldoQQOro.Value), 0)` pero el resultado me da **1100** cuando debería de ser **550**

Cabe aclarar que todos los datos vienen de una base de datos en sql, en la cual yo ejecuto un procedimiento almacenado y este me devuelve una consulta

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Para lograr eso debes primeramente trabajar con grupos en los reportes

Comment: Actualmente estoy manejando un grupo primario, este me agrupa todos los exportadores pero aún así escribiendo las fórmulas anteriormente mencionas no funciona

Comment: Usas el wizard de reportviewer?

Comment: No, los hago desde cero

Comment: El wizard te va a ayudar mucho, trata de usarlo

Comment: Ok haré de nuevo el reporte utilizando el wizard, gracias por la sugerencia!

Comment: Resolviste algo?